# Balls without being together (Exercise)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have the following problem, it's of my old maths contest, and i'd like to see how can i solve it because i'm not really good at this math area.

**Exercise 2.-** If you have 5 blue balls, 5 red balls and 5 white balls, How many ways can you order them without blue balls together?

I did this:

$P_n^{5,5,5}$ - $P_{n-4}^{5-4,5,5}$ = $\frac{15!}{5!5!5!}$ - $\frac{11!}{1!5!5!}$

But i don't think it's correct, i don't even have more ideas. I'd like to do it by a binomial coefficient or by any permutation/variation formula.  I would appreciate for any help, thanks.

Comment: All $5$ blue balls together, or any $2$ (or more) blue balls together?

Comment: any 2 or more blue balls.

Comment: Well, you've answered the first option, and I've answered both in any case (see below)...

Comment: Yes, i saw it, but how did you did it? i still having some problems understanding it, sorry

Comment: Arrange the red and white, and then choose $5$ slots out of $5+5+1$ slots for the blue.

Comment: Thank you very much! i think with this i'm able to understand a lot of problems more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without all $5$ blue balls together:

$$\frac{(5+5+5)!}{5!\times5!\times5!}-\frac{(5+5+1)!}{5!\times5!\times1!}$$

---

> Without any $2$ blue balls together:

$$\frac{(5+5)!}{5!\times5!}\times\binom{5+5+1}{5}$$